# Как получить данные от fetch запроса при включенном cors

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Пишу программу которая должна брать данные из php файла. На внешнем сервере *(на котором находится этот php файл)* включен CORS. Я могу только отправлять запросы с `mode: 'no-cors'`. Подскажите каким методом получить данные с сайта не меняя при этом настройки безопасности?

Answer (score 0):

Очень легко реализовать через [JSONP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). Набивка из php должна вызвать javascript процедуру с ответом: `response("data")`. Тогда, создавая скрипт `<script src="jsonp.php?q=response"></script>`, он подкачает ответ php и выполнит его, функция ответа должна быть определена на странице заранее. Дедовский способ обхода настройки CORS.

Comment: У меня сервер возвращает не json ответ, а генерирует html таблицу. Если отправить запрос на php, то во вкладке "сеть", в ответе я получу html код. Что делать в таком случае? Или при помощи jsonp можно получить данные и таким образом?

Comment: Ну вы можете написать на php такую страничку, в которой обернете вывод в jsonp. Достаточно просто прописать вызов с строкой html. Но он должен быть, так как доступ к загруженному контенту не можете получить пока тот скрипт не вызовет вашу процедуру, с необходимыми для вас данными в качестве аргумента. Вы поняли механизм обмена?

Comment: Приблизительно, я попробую разобраться, т.к. не работал с межсерверными  запросами. Спасибо за наводку